# Google Adwords Conversion in Lightbox Popup?

Tags: google-analytics, lightbox, pixel, google-ads-api

Trying to figure out how this can be accomplished... =/

The regular Google Analytics code doesn't track in a javascript lightbox popup, so we had to use a Analytics custom event for tracking.

I believe we might be running into the same problem now with our Google Adwords conversion pixel that we're trying to add into another lightbox popup after the ones with Event Tracking on them.

I can't find any other topics anywhere on this subject. Is this possible or able to be done using another method similar to how Event Tracking can be used with Analytics?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly doable with some Javascript voodoo, but a much easier solution would probably be to set up your Analytics event (that you already have) as a goal, and then [import this goal as a conversion into Adwords](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034306?hl=en). Note that this solution requires you to [link your Analytics and Adwords accounts.](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/1704341?hl=en)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch that this is *another* lightbox. But you just need to add a similar Analytics event there.